# Error duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/location/places/zzj.class

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services, google-places-api

I am having this error when I try to run my project:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException:    duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/location/places/zzj.class

Here is the build.gradle file I am using:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
        classpath 'io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:0.89.1'
    }
}
apply plugin: "com.android.library"
apply plugin: "realm-android"

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1"
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1"
    compile "com.android.support:design:23.1.1"
    compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.1.2"
    compile ('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.9.0')
        { exclude group: 'com.android.support' }
    compile ('com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:7.2.2')
        { exclude group: 'com.android.support' }
    compile "com.pubnub:pubnub-android:3.7.6"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.0"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.0"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.0"
    compile ('com.appyvet:materialrangebar:1.3')
        { exclude group: 'com.android.support' }
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.5'
    compile "com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.2.10"
    compile "com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.2.10"
    compile ('com.instabug.library:instabug:2.1')
        { exclude group: 'com.android.support' }
    compile 'com.github.tony19:logback-android-core:1.1.1-4'
    compile 'com.github.tony19:logback-android-classic:1.1.1-4'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.6'
    compile 'ch.acra:acra:4.8.2'
    compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.1.15'
    compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

Comment: You have a duplicate dependency. It seems that you have two versions of the google places api.

Comment: @Emmanuel That's what I've thought about too. But, I am just using one dependency of google places API. I can't see where it can be duplicated !!

Comment: run `./gradlew :android:dependencies` on the terminal. One of the other libraries you are using probably depends on an earlier version of the google places library. You need to find the library that brings in the dependency and exclude google places from it.

Comment: @Emmanuel I still can't find it. Anything else to do ?

Comment: Another person with the same issue described resolving by looking for com.google.android.gms in other build.gradle files from included modules...  see link: https://medium.com/@suchydan/how-to-solve-google-play-services-version-collision-in-gradle-dependencies-ef086ae5c75f

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I have upgraded google play services (maps, location and gcm) from 9.0.0 to 9.2.0

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.2.0'
```

Then I have added this dependency:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.2.0'
```

And it works like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

I added the latest version of com.google.android.gms from:
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases 
and added `force = true` for the gms modules I use:

```
    compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.0.2') {
        force = true;
    }
    compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.2') {
        force = true;
    }
    compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.2') {
        force = true;
    }
```